# Change text on click not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do the typical Show/Hide menu with javascript or Jquery.
The issue I'm having is that font awesome icons or bootstrap seem to be messing up the .text() function so that there is extra spacing and my if statements won't work as expected. Hoping to get this to work cross-browser too.

```js
$('#list-btn').click(function() {

  var el = $('#list-btn')
  console.log(el.text())


  if (el.text() == el.text("Hide Instructions")) {
    el.text("Show Instructions");
  } else {

    el.text("Hide Instructions");
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li>
  <a href="#" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" data-toggle="tab" id="list-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-list white"></i>&nbsp;Hide Instructions</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Try : `if (el.text() == "Hide Instructions")`

Comment: @Fr33d0m from the console it is still showing spaces when I print the text, and it removes the icon. I think the first if statement doesn't match the text because of the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct the comparison.

```
if (el.text().trim() === "Hide Instructions"){
```

However, I would recommend you to wrap the text in a `span`. It will prevent the `<i>` element from being removed when the `text()` operation is performed.

```js
$('#list-btn').click(function() {
  var el = $('span', this)
  console.log(el.text())
  if (el.text().trim() == "Hide Instructions") {
    el.text("Show Instructions");
  } else {
    el.text("Hide Instructions");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<li>
  <a href="#" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" data-toggle="tab" id="list-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-list white"></i>&nbsp;<span>Hide Instructions</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks, also your explanation is great!  Will accept!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (el.text().trim() === "Hide Instructions"){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list-btn').off().on('click',function() {

   var el = $('#list-btn')
  console.log(el)


  if (el.text() == "Hide Instructions") {
    el.text("Show Instructions");
  } else {

    el.text("Hide Instructions");
  }
  });
});
</script>
```